# Now to make path aliases of imports visible in nuxt.config.ts?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

In this question, I **don't** talk about`NuxtConfig.alias` property which usually looks like:

```
const Config: NuxtConfig = {
  alias: {
    "@EnterpriseBusinessRules": Path.resolve(__dirname, "BusinessRules", "Enterprise"),
    "@ApplicationBusinessRules": Path.resolve(__dirname, "BusinessRules", "Application"),
    // ...
}
```

What I am talking about is:

```
import EnvironmentVariables from "@Environment/EnvironmentVariables";
import RawObjectDataProcessor from "@Utils/RawObjectDataProcessor/RawObjectDataProcessor";
```

in `nuxt.config.ts`.

The `nuxt` command (currently supporting the TypeScript making `nuxt-ts` obsolete) does not see this aliases. It will be the error like:

```
FATAL  Cannot find module '@Utils/RawObjectDataProcessor/RawObjectDataProcessor'                                       11:22:55
Require stack:
- C:\Users\XXXXX\ExamppleProject\nuxt.config.ts
```

Of course, all aliases has been declared in `tsconfig.json`.

Even we will not import anything via path alias to `nuxt.config.ts`, the imported via relative path modules could use the path aliases inside themselves, so we can not run away from this problem with "You should not import via aliases to `nuxt.config.ts`".